# react-scripts: command not found (npm start)

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

I've been using `create-react-app` without issues for some time, but recently, after running it, I cannot start the development server. After running `npm start`, I get the following error:

```
sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! js-calculator@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the js-calculator@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Scripts appear to be in the correct location and correctly configured in the `package.json` file.
Also, `npm start` throws me the same error if I run it in other react-apps folders that used to work before.
I tried various suggestions I found here on stackoverflow:

- installing create-react-app globally;
- reinstalling dependencies (`npm install`);
- reinstalling react scripts (`npm install react-scripts --save`);
- updating node and npm;

but none of the above worked.

Any suggestions?
I've also a more detailed `.log` file, in case anyone wants to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

After many tries and more reading of related issues here on SO, I found the cause. One of my react-app parent folders (five levels above) name was "**example/example**"; naming it to "**example-example**" solved the problem.